# Kendo grid read request datetime filter issue: How to send dates in Utc or at least with timeoffset info?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I think the issue is not ASP MVC (kendo version) related, but just for the info I am using that, especially 2015.1.408.

When the grid (hence the datasource) has a datetime filter set, and the grid issues a Read request to the server it serializes its filter and this serialized string is part of the request called parameter 'filter' along with other parameters like, page, pageSize, sort, etc.

Unfortunately the filter text is **not** Json:

```
(LevelInt~gte~-2147483648~and~DateTime~gte~datetime'2015-06-19T00-00-00'~and~DateTime~lte~datetime'2015-06-19T23-59-59')
```

The problem is that the datetimes are *exactly* that values what the user entered at the client in its timezone, but *without this timezone* information.

Consequently it is not possible to know what was it really... and unable to filter if all the data in the DB stored in UTC.

To express it more clearly: This serializing is an explicit information loss. Either the datetime should be UTC or the timezone should be provided along with the date somehow. (Imagine a db filled with events like log, all date in UTC, for **many** reasons. We must have the query dates in UTC, or know its timezone to correctly convert to UTC)

*** Edit: ***

Steps to reproduce:

1. Launch Fiddler
2. Goto this demo: [Simple kendo data grid with
   Date filtering](http://dojo.telerik.com/AzaKo)
3. Use the Order Date columns filter. Do not waste
   your time to pick dates what will have more than 0 result, just pick
   a date.
4. Switch to Fiddler and find the datasource datarequest
   requst. See the picture below:

[image]

Now I must find a workaround.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you convert the filter date to UTC on the client before you send it to the server?

Comment: @RickS. 1) This is a kendo component. It (not me) stores the filter data at client side correctly in a native javascript Date with the correct timezone info. Nothing to convert on that. 2) That's not me who sends the data. Its the grid/datasource component, say when the user selects page 3 in the grid.

Comment: Before you send the data to the server, convert it to UTC.  Maybe it would be helpful to see your code...

Comment: Rick S: and again: That is not me who sends the data. This is a kendo component. Its the grid/datasource component, say when the user selects page 3 in the grid.

Comment: Is serverfiltering set to true? If it is, then you can convert the dates or pass whatever information you need to your server filter process.

Comment: Rick: Exactly. Server filtering, and what I see in the server?  To answer this, one should read the original question: I see that string, what I've quoted as code, plus no timezone information. I do not what to parse unique strings, in server side, and I do not want extra task to ask client for its timezone. That's the issue about, as I wrote: it is explicit information loss and forces developer to manipulate and parse custom strings.

Comment: I don't understand where that string of data is coming from.  According to the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-serverFiltering), the filter is not sent that way.  That's why I asked for you to post your code.  If you don't want to share any code, then no one will be able to help you.  Or at least give us a way to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: Rick: Kendo demos are public, and all I described is not _specific_ to my application, it is a general concept flaw/issue in the Kendo grid's internal working. Anyone can try and reproduce the described use case. Please see  my edit and detailed steps how (the dojo page created by one click on the original Telerik Kendo demo page)

Comment: Use [parameterMap](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap) to update the filter to include the timezone.